# Playing a specific sound according to random array outcome?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova, audio, media

I am making a 'Username' generator in javascript using 2 arrays filled with words, then using randomization to display 1 word from each array. However, say I want to play a specific sound labelled '1.mp3' when the second word gets chosen in the first array, and play a sound labelled '8.mp3' when the ninth word gets chosen in the second array. These sounds would play on page load in order of first array sound, then second array sound. I'm using cordova's Media plugin for phone support. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

The Javascript array looks like this:

```
var wordlist1 = ["Aggressive", "Amazing", "Attractive", "Black", "Broken", "Brave",
"Caring", "Cold", "Corny", "Delicious", "Dramatic", "Dull", "Euphoric", "Exotic",
"Evil", "Fabulous", "Feminine", "Fat", "Glorious", "Gripping", "Grand", "Hairy", 
"Horny", "Hard", "Immense", "Idiotic", "Inferior", "Jam-Packed", "Juicy", "Jealous", 
"Kooky", "Klutzy", "Knowledgeable", "Lame", "Lazy", "Loving", "Mad", "Milky", "Moist", 
"Naive", "Naughty", "Neglected", "Oily", "Obese", "Overcooked", "Passionate", "Party",
"Peaceful", "Pasty", "Questionable", "Queasy", "Qualified", "Reckless", "Repulsive",
"Rubbery", "Slimy", "Salty", "Stiff", "Thick", "Terrible", "Thunderous", "Ugly",
"Uncomfortable", "Unpleasant", "Violent", "Vivid", "Vicious", "Wobbly", "Wee", "Wet",
"Young", "Yummy", "Yellowish", "Zany", "Zappy", "Zealous"]
var displayword1 = wordlist1[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist1.length)];
document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = displayword1
```

the second array is nearly identical save for contents of array & name
I then have an HTML document that will load the script;

```
<p id="word1"></p>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please add some code that describes what you have done so far?

Comment: I have edited the original post with some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var wordlist1 = ["Aggressive", "Amazing", "Attractive", "Black", "Broken", "Brave",
"Caring", "Cold", "Corny"]


var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist1.length);
var displayword1 = wordlist1[randomNumber];
document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = displayword1
var media = new Media(randomNumber+".mp3", function(){/*success*/}, function(){/*error*/});
media.play();
```

maybe you will need to change the success callback to be the one calling this.play();

Comment: if you want to map specific files to specific words i would suggest using an array of objects /collection.

    var wordlist1 = [{word:"Aggressive",file:"1.mp3"},{word:"Aggressive",file:"2.mp3"}]
    
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordlist1.length);
    var displayword1 = wordlist1[randomNumber].word;
    var soundToPlay =  wordlist1[randomNumber].file;
    document.getElementById("word1").innerHTML = displayword1
    var media = new Media(soundToPlay, function(){/*success*/}, function(){/*error*/});
    media.play();

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although both of your answers seem like they would work, for some reason it isn't playing the sounds for me. Any idea why? :/

Comment: have you debug this with a console?
is the filepath correct? what happens when you put in a remote url?